# codeigniter migrate to linux server page was not found

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

i done develop application by using codeigniter running on the window localhost and working it fine but problem is when i migrated to linux server got error message '404 Page Not Found'.base_url already changed.

Localhost 
-localhost/ci/index.php/test (window)
output: successful

Server 
-172.16.10.251/ci/index.php/test- (linux)
output:404 Page Not Found

Question

is there any setting i miss to change?

sorry first time make it online.

thank you

Comment: try to put some test page on root of the server and check it is working or not.

Comment: have you any htaccess?

Comment: i copy all folder from htdoc(xampp) to www in Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) then change base_url to ip address of the server. unfortunately still not working

Comment: please change your config base url like this in /var/www/ci/application/config.php  ` $config['base_url']= 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/ci/'; `

Comment: i think issues on index.php..already create htacess but can't load

Comment: did you solve this problem ? I am facing the same problem now. It's so frustrating

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.
I think the problem lies on the case sensitivity of Linux.
So I encourage you to change all of your files under controllers and models with capital Letter. I managed to solve the same problem using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

windows And Linux has different sensitive case so I thing You just change file in controller and models whit capital Letter. it work to me